# How do I import a dataframe created in one module for processing the same in a new module?

Tags: python, class, oop, module

I have a data frame generated from a class (i.e. a module that will be imported to another file) that takes a URL and generates a data frame extracting data from the tables available in the URL. Now the doubt I have is regarding: I want to write a class to preprocess the data frame and generate an inverted index. How do I import the data frame I generated in a different module in a generalized fashion?

While it's very simple to paste a specific URL into the method defined in the earlier class, I need to find a  way to generalize the process.

`enter code here`def dict2df():
`enter code here`enter code here`dict = {Numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'Name': ['Oz', 'Doz', 'Moz', 'Woz', 'Hoz', 'Loz']}`
enter code here``enter code here`df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

```
enter code here`enter code here`return df
```

I generate a file search.py

And now, I create another module to do some stuff on the df. How do I import this df object and not the df itself (for generalizability reasons) into another module to perform the preprocessing?

I need to import a data frame object and not the specific data frame itself, created in one module to another module. While I could easily derive a specific data frame, I have not been able to figure out how to retrieve the data frame object.

Comment: Please show some of your code in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the URL has to do with it, but you can easily copy specific columns form one data frame to another data frame.  See the examples below.

```
new = old[['A', 'C', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']].copy()

new = old.filter(['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], axis=1)
```

There are almost certainly other ways to do this as well.  I'll leave it to you to discover other options for doing the same.  Hope this helps.

Comment: As in I pass a URL into this custom class .and if there is a table in the page, the title and content of those specific pages will be retrieved as a data frame object. Thank you for the help. Can you also help me sort out another problem? Now that I have created the dataframe and have imported the class/module to another file, I am not able to subscript the DF to do the preprocessing as it is a part of 'def __init__(self, df)'. How do I sort that out?